# xcode 4.2 with ios5.1

Tags: xcode

I have Xcode version 4.2 with OS X 10.7.2, and I was trying to install our app on the new iPad, which is running iOS 5.1. The problem is Xcode doesn't recognize the iPad as a deployable device. I know this is a common issue, but please read it all.

I get this in the organizer: (after push the "use for development")

```
The version of iOS on “iPad” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.


OS Installed on iPad
5.1 (9B176)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3
4.2
```

Now I know that in order to connect the iOS 5.1 device to Xcode I need the latest release of Xcode, but I can connect another iPhone with iOS 5.1 to the same Xcode and deploy an app to it.

Why is that?

The only different between them is that this iPhone was previously connected to Xcode, and the iPad was not. I did manage to install an app to iPhone with iOS 5.1!

What is happening here? I don't want to install the new Xcode for nothing if I can install to 5.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode will not let you build to an iOS version higher than it supports, and in this case with Xcode 4.2, you will not be able to deploy to iOS 5.1. I recommend updating to OS X Lion 10.7.3 and downloading the 4.3.2 version of Xcode. Do this any you will be able to deploy to your 5.1 device without any problems. In addition to this, the second device should not be able to receive builds from Xcode. Please check and see if the device in question is in fact running iOS 5.0.1 and not 5.1 as 5.1 will not work on Xcode 4.2 and 5.0.1 will.

Comment: this is not true. i actually discovered somthing new. i manage to program this ipad, with this method: if i need to program an ios5.1 device , i just have to connect it the another xcode that is newer , then back to my computer , and it works. we have tried that with many more devices in our company . strange !

Comment: @user1280535 - can you please elaborate this? I am going through a similar issue.